Union and Intersection of Infinite Number of Intervals

Some thoughts I had are:
A. The only substraction possible are limited to intervals that are in the range of 0 to 1, since as n goes to infinity, intersection must include some values from 0 to 1.
B. Intervals for odd j which are less than some negative value greater than -1 cannot be sustracted.
C. Intervals for even j which are more than some positive value less than 1.5 cannot be sustracted.
I have some other thoughts but I am not sure they are correct. Your help is very appriciated. Thanks.
Following Steen82's answer, this is what I got for even j:
$$\left[\tfrac{(-1)^{j+1}}{{j+1}},\tfrac{(-1)^{j}}{j}\right)\cup \left(1+\tfrac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1},1+\tfrac{(-1)^{j}}{j}\right]$$

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwsie present in your post. See here for why. Your images also seem particularly, and unnecessarily, large.

Please include your thoughts.

"section" has a meaning in mathematics, but it doesn't seem that that's what you intend.  Did you mean "interval"?

Can you computer the intersection? How about the union? Have you tried this for small $n$ instead of $\infty$ to see if there is a pattern?

The key observation is that $\tfrac{1}{n}$ is a decreasing function of $n$.
For the union you want $\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}, n\geq j$ to be as small as possible and $1+\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ to be as large as possible.
For the intersection you want $\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}, n\geq j$ to be as large as possible and $1+\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ to be as small as possible.
So, if $j$ is odd the union is $\left[\tfrac{(-1)^j}{j},1+\tfrac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1}\right]$ and the intersection is $\left[\tfrac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1},1+\tfrac{(-1)^{j}}{j}\right].$ Hence, the difference is $\left[\tfrac{(-1)^j}{j},\tfrac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1}\right)\cup \left(1+\tfrac{(-1)^{j}}{j},1+\tfrac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1}\right] $.
I will let you work out the case where $j$ is even, since it is similar.

At least for the intersection, I think it can't go beyond 1 from above because as n goes to infinity, the intersection is bounded by the [0 1] interval...

Say $j=3$ then $1+\tfrac{(-1)^j}{j} =1+\tfrac{(-1)^3}{3}=\tfrac{2}{3}<1.$

Thanks allot for your answers. I added the case for even j in my question. I would appriciate if you can take a look...

Your $j$ even answers looks good to me.
